# HTML, CSS, JS: Guessing Game WebPage with Buttons and EventListeners: Hint and Reset Buttons Are Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, button, reset, event-listener

I am new to web dev and am trying to create a functioning Guessing Game that uses HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

The purpose of the game is to give players 5 chances to guess the right number between 1 and 100.

In my webpage, the reset and hint buttons do not appear to work and I don't know what's wrong.

You can try the full game (with graphics and all) [here](https://pinzhi000.github.io/FSA_guessingGame/guessing-game-master/).

Below is my code, as a snippet for testing.:

```js
// 1

function generateWinningNumber(min, max) {
  min = 1;
  max = 100;

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// 2

function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length,
    t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}



// 3

class Game {

  constructor() {
    // hold the player's number guess
    this.playersGuess = null;
    // will be an array, and holds all of the player's past guesses
    this.pastGuesses = []
    // winningNumber property, which calls generateWinningNumber
    this.winningNumber = generateWinningNumber()
  }

  // methods 
  difference() {
    return Math.abs(this.playersGuess - this.winningNumber)
  }

  isLower() {
    if (this.playersGuess < this.winningNumber) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  playersGuessSubmission(num) {
    this.playersGuess = num;

    if (typeof num !== 'number' || num < 1 || num > 100) throw 'That is an invalid guess.';
    return this.checkGuess(num);
  }


  checkGuess(num) {

    // player won
    if (this.playersGuess === this.winningNumber) {
      return "You Win!"
    }

    // player lost 
    if (this.pastGuesses.length >= 5) {
      return 'You Lose'
    }

    // player guesses duplicate number
    if (this.pastGuesses.includes(this.playersGuess)) {
      return "You have already guessed that number.";
    }

    // player wrong guess or already guessed number
    if (this.playersGuess !== this.winningNumber || this.pastGuesses.includes(this.playersGuess)) {
      this.pastGuesses.push(this.playersGuess)
    }

    // off by less than 10
    if (Math.abs(this.playersGuess - this.winningNumber) < 10) {
      return "You\'re burning up!"
    }

    // off by less than 25
    if (Math.abs(this.playersGuess - this.winningNumber) < 25) {
      return "You\'re lukewarm."
    }

    // off by less than 50
    if (Math.abs(this.playersGuess - this.winningNumber) < 50) {
      return "You\'re a bit chilly."
    }

    // off by less than 100
    if (Math.abs(this.playersGuess - this.winningNumber) < 100) {
      return "You\'re ice cold!"
    }

  }

  // provide hint 
  provideHint() {

    let arrayHints = [generateWinningNumber(), generateWinningNumber(), generateWinningNumber(), this.winningNumber, generateWinningNumber()]
    return shuffle(arrayHints)
  }
}



// newGame function returns an empty, new game instance //

function newGame() {
  const startGame = new Game();
  return startGame;
}


/***************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************************/

// PLAY GUESSING GAME 

function makeGuess() {

  // create a new instance of Guessing Game using newGame function from previous code 
  let game = newGame();

  // player inputs numerical guess into input box and clicks on Submit button 
  const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitBtn');

  // add event listener for clicking
  submitButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    // take input value
    const numGuess = Number(document.querySelector('input').value);
    console.log(numGuess);

    // get output message associated with guess
    const guessMessage = game.playersGuessSubmission(numGuess)
    console.log('game message:', guessMessage, ' winning number:', game.winningNumber, 'past guesses:', game.pastGuesses);

    // reset input box after submission
    document.querySelector('input').value = '';

    // set game messages produced by checkGuess method 
    document.querySelector('#messages > h2').innerHTML = guessMessage;
    document.querySelector(`#guess-list li:nth-child(${game.pastGuesses.length})`).innerHTML = game.playersGuess;

    // RESET & HINT

    // enable reset button to work
    const resetButton = document.getElementById('resetBtn')

    // add eventListener 
    resetButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Reset Everything')

      // error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>
      // document.querySelector('messages>h2').innerHTML = 'Game Over!';
      game = newGame();
    });

    // enable hint button to work
    const hintButton = document.getElementById('hintBtn')

    // add eventListener 
    hintButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      console.log('Give Hint')

      // display hint where messages normally show 
      document.querySelector('messages>h2').innerHTML = `correct value is in: ${provideHint()}`
    });


  });
}



/***************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************************************************/

// PLAY GAME!  

makeGuess()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dwight Schrute's Bidding Blunder</title>

  <!-- the MAIN.CSS file is linked here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="guessing-game.css">


</head>

<body>

  <body class='bg' background="dwight_schrute.jpg"></body>


  <h1 align="center">Dwight Schrute's Bidding Blunder</h1>

  <div class="youTubeLink">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhsng72lC4s">The Office Episode: Bidding Blunder</a>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p id="p1">BEFORE I GUESS</p>
    <p id="p2">ANYTHING</p>
    <p id="p3">I ASK MYSELF</p>
    <p id="p4">"WOULD AN IDIOT DO THAT?"</p>
    <p id="p5">AND IF THE ANSWER IS YES</p>
    <p id="p6">I DO NOT GUESS THAT</p>
    <br>
    <p id="p7">-Dwight Schrute</p>
  </div>

  <div id="game-box" class="center">
    <h2 id="PG">Previous Guesses</h2>

    <ul id="guess-list">
      <li class="guess">Guess #1 | ? |</li>
      <li class="guess">Guess #2 | ? |</li>
      <li class="guess">Guess #3 | ? |</li>
      <li class="guess">Guess #4 | ? |</li>
      <li class="guess">Guess #5 | ? |</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div>
    <input placeholder="enter">
    <button id="submitBtn">Submit</button>
    <button id="resetBtn">Reset</button>
    <button id="hintBtn">Hint</button>
  </div>


  <figure>
    <img src="thought_bubble.png" class="bubble" alt="Guess" />
    <figcaption>You Have Five <br>Guesses! <br> Answer between <br>1 and 100</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <div id='messages'>
    <h2></h2>
  </div>


  <!-- uncomment the script tag above when you are ready to add JavaScript to your document -->
  <script src='js/guessing-game.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

What's missing with my reset and hint code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have `document.querySelector('messages>h2')`, but you should have `document.querySelector('#messages>h2')` (see lines 185 and 187).

You are looking for an element with ID `messages`. Thus you need to use `#` to specify that you are looking for an ID, as you did in other parts of your code.

After fixing the previous issues, note that the call to `provideHint()` is not working. You need an instance of `Game` (replace it with `(new Game).provideHint()` to see it working) or to [make the function static](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) (and use `Game.provideHint()`). You can try to refactor it after understanding the previous topics.